# Why is zero not a subnormal number?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

The IEEE-754 standard defines subnormal numbers such that the two zeros are explicitly excluded. What's the rationale for this decision, and does this mean that the performance penalty for subnormals does not apply to zero?

Comment: I wonder if it is because there might be a reduced level of IEEE-754 compliance that allows not supporting _subnormals_?  In such cases, +/- 0.0 would still be needed and so not a subnormal.

Comment: Re "does this mean that the performance penalty for subnormals does not apply to zero". Not all platforms have such a performance penalty, that is an (admittedly common) implementation artifact. Where such performance penalties exist, they do not affect zeros. The penalties arise from the need to normalize subnormals on input and denormalize when generating subnormal results; neither applies to zero.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Support for subnormals is not an optional part of the IEEE-754 floating-point standard (i.e. not covered by "should" clauses). This was a major point of contention in the run-up to the issuance of the standard. While a platform lacking subnormal support therefore cannot be compliant with IEEE-754, it can still be compatible with the standard.

Comment: I suspect this is mostly a terminological thing.  I've always thought that 0 is, at least in effect, a subnormal: it clearly occupies the same binade as the subnormals, and perhaps more importantly, it obviously does not — and here it's just like the subnormals! — have an implicit 1 bit.

Comment: If someone says that 0 is not a subnormal, it's sort of like saying that 1 is not a prime number.  This isn't a perfect analogy, but my point is that definitional categorizations like these can be somewhat arbitrary, not necessarily perfectly aligned with actual functionality.  0 shares some — but not quite all — of the properties of the subnormals, so someone declared that it isn't one.  1 shares some — but not quite all — of the properties of a prime, so most mathematicians have declared that it isn't one.

Comment: I fully agree, but also, that's exactly the point: 1 is not considered a prime number because it does not have many of the properties of the other primes. So if 0 is not considered a subnormal, then that's probably because it lacks some of the properties of the other subnormals. But I just can't think of what these properties would be. As far as I can tell, 0 is fully covered by the general subnormal arithmetic, so the only way how 0 could be special is if we declare it such, and the only reason I can see for doing that is because we want to boost its performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's important to recognize that IEEE-754 is a standard for the behavior of conforming implementations. It talks about "what", not "how". It is not a guide on how to effectively implement that behavior, in software or in hardware. The fact that zero has the bit pattern and semantics of a subnormal is *interesting* and *clearly not an accident* but is *not what the standard is here to talk about*.

Second of all, a bit of history: subnormals are one of the weirder aspects of IEEE-754. Plenty of previous approaches to floating point didn't support them. To this day, the majority of 754 implementations either allow them to be toggled off, support them only through software fallbacks, or don't support them at all.

Subnormals were, and are, seen as a "last line of defense": You wouldn't generally intentionally use them as inputs, but having them available as outputs helps with the robustness of FP-using algorithms. Sterbenz's theorem (you can exactly subtract any two FP numbers which differ by less than a factor of two) is a good example of this. But the difficulty of efficiently implementing subnormal arithmetic was recognized at the time.

Needless to say, the number zero is pretty common. Operations involving zero are *not* done using the code/circuitry which supports subnormals, because that would be slow, and it's trivially easy to special-case zero inputs instead.

So, to sum up: Zero was not described as a "subnormal number" because the important practical aspects of subnormal numbers (i.e. the slowness) do not apply to it.